# Is it possible to transform compiled javascript, and to configure the order that transformers are run?

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I have a use-case for a pub transformer that isn't very typical, so I'm wondering if it's possible.  I'd like to individually gzip every css, html, and javascript file produced during pub build.  I have two questions about this:

- Is it possible to transform compiled javascript?
- Is it possible to configure the order that the transformer is run?  Obviously, the gzip transformer would need to be the last transformer run.

In case you're wondering why I want to do this, I'm serving my app via S3 which doesn't support on-the-fly gzipping.  I figure pub transformers would be the most appropriate place to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify order by the line position of the transformer:

```
transformers:
  - $dart2js
  - YourGzipTransformer
```

The above specifies that you want the dart2js transformer to run before YourGzipTransformer, thereby giving YourGzipTransformer access to the Javascript files generated by dart2js. If you swapped the order, or did not specify the order of the dart2js transformer, YourGzipTransformer would run before it and not have access to the compiled Javascript.

If you didn't care what order some transformers ran in, you could specify that too:

```
transformers:
  - [$dart2js, SomeOtherTransformer]
  - YourGzipTransformer
```

You can read more about this in the [Assets and Transformers article](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/assets-and-transformers.html#specifying-transformers).

Here's a basic transformer that will generate a gzipped version of every CSS, HTML, and Javascript file:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:barback/barback.dart';

class GzipTransformer extends Transformer {
  final BarbackSettings _settings;

  GzipTransformer.asPlugin(this._settings);

  @override
  Future apply(Transform transform) {
    return transform.primaryInput.readAsString().then((content) {
        var id = transform.primaryInput.id;
        var gzipId = id.changeExtension(id.extension +".gzip");

        var gzippedContent = GZIP.encode(content.codeUnits);
        transform.addOutput(new Asset.fromBytes(gzipId, gzippedContent));
      });
  }

  String get allowedExtensions => ".js .css .html";

}
```